# How to wait for internal promises to finish

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am using `fs.readdir` to get a list of directories and then again in the callback to get a list of "subpages" in each of these directories. I would like for the first callback to wait until the second callback is completed but I'm not sure how to do that.

```js
// Array to hold list of pages
const pageList = []

// Get contents of target directory (not recursive)
fs.readdir(targetDir, { withFileTypes: true }, (err, items) => {
  // Stop and return if error
  if (!!err) return err

  // Go through found contents
  const theseItems = items.map(item => {
    const subpages = []

    // Directory name
    const dirName = item.name

    // Set up published target for this directory
    const thisTargetDir = targetDir + '/' + dirName + '/publish'

    // Now get pages in the directory's published directory
    // (assumes all files within subdirectories are .mdx pages to load)
    return (
      fs.readdir(thisTargetDir, { withFileTypes: true }, (err, pages) => {
        const theseSubpages = pages.map(page => {
          const mdxSuffix = /.mdx$/g
          const pageName = page.name.replace(mdxSuffix, '')

          return subpages.push({ name: pageName })
        })

        Promise.all(theseSubpages).then(() => {
          // Add to page list array
          pageList.push({ name: dirName, subpages: subpages })
        })
      })
    )
  })

  Promise.all(theseItems).then(() => {
    console.log('pageList at the end is: ')
    console.log(pageList)
  })
})
```

The `Promise.all(theseSubpages)` works as expected, however the `Promise.all(theseItems)` resolves before the former has a chance to cycle through. I understand why that's happening and I've tried to do things like return each `item` as a Promise.resolve(), etc. but these things aren't working.

Wondering if I'm doing something inherently wrong in this approach…

**UPDATE**

I tried using the `fsPromises` approach but kept running into the same wrong patterns. Ended up using the [node-dir](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-dir) package to go through the directories recursively. Code below, not really the exact answer to what I was trying to do, but this gets the result I was looking for.

```js
const dir = require('node-dir')

const targetDir = __dirname + '/../pages/stuff'
const pageList = []

dir.paths(targetDir, (err, paths) => {
  if (err) throw err

  const baseMatch = __dirname.replace('/lib', '') + '/pages/stuff'

  paths.dirs.map(dir => {
    // Only publish paths
    if (dir.substr(-7) === 'publish') {
      // Get the slug directly before publish path
      const contentSlug = dir.split('/').slice(-2)[0]

      // Add this to main pageList array as top level objects
      pageList.push({ name: contentSlug, subpages: [] })
    }
  })

  paths.files.map(file => {
    const filePathArray = file.split('/')

    // Only publish paths
    if (filePathArray.slice(-2)[0] === 'publish') {
      // Get parent content slug for matching purposes
      const parentContentSlug = filePathArray.slice(-3)[0]

      // Get file name (remove .mdx suffix)
      const mdxSuffix = /.mdx$/g
      const fileName = filePathArray.slice(-1)[0].replace(mdxSuffix, '')

      // Loop through main page list, find match, then add file as subpage
      pageList.find((obj, key) => {
        if (obj.name === parentContentSlug) {
          return pageList[key].subpages.push({ name: fileName })
        }
      })
    }
  })

  console.log('pageList at end:')
  console.log(pageList)
})
```

Comment: You aren't returning promises to either of those arrays. The map() for `theseSubpages` is synchronous and doesn't need `Promise.all()` either

Comment: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api

Comment: If you are using a recent version of node you can use the [fs Promises API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api). Using that together with async/await would make this a lot cleaner.

Comment: What is that `return fs.readdir()` supposed to do? `readdir` uses Node's callback convention, so you don't "return its result", you do your work as part of the callback, the function itself returns nothing meaningful.

Comment: I was hoping that would force it to wait for everything in there to complete in the last Promise.all

Comment: @MarkMeyer I'm looking through all of that now via @Jonas’s link above

Comment: Suggest you take some time put to learn Array methods. Used correctly, they are powerful things that will help you write concise code.

Answer (score 0):

Promises work by chaining `.then` calls (`Promise.then(doStuff)`). If you start a promise but then don't chain, you can't know when it's done. In order to chain promises from inner functions you have to return promises.

Generally you don't want to mix callbacks and promises.

If I were to do this I would start by using just promises.

```
const readdir = (target, options) =>
  // returns a promise that resolves or rejects when the call finishes
  new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    fs.readdir(target, options, (err, result) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve(result);
    })
  );

const collectSubPages = pages =>
  // Wait for all the promises in the array to resolve
  Promise.all(
    // for each page, return a promise that resolves to the page/subpage object
    pages.map(({ name }) =>
      readdir(targetDir + "/" + name + "/publish", {
        withFileTypes: true
      })
        .then(subpages => subpages.map(({ name }) => ({ name })))
        .then(subpages => ({ name, subpages }))
    )
  );


readdir(targetDir, { withFileTypes: true })
  .then(pages => collectSubPages(pages))
  .then(console.log);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips here, I ended up just using an NPM package to go through the directories recursively.

Comment: Note that `const readdir = require('util').promisify(fs.readdir)` is a built-in transform function for Node.js that does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

@David Yeiser, your own "update" code can be written more concisely using Array methods [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), plus various optimisations, as follows :

```
const dir = require('node-dir');
const targetDir = __dirname + '/../pages/stuff';
dir.paths(targetDir, (err, paths) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    const baseMatch = __dirname.replace('/lib', '') + '/pages/stuff';
    const mdxSuffix = /.mdx$/g; // define once, use many times
    const fileList = paths.files
        .map(fileName => fileName.split('/'))
        .filter(filePathArray => filePathArray[filePathArray.length - 2] === 'publish'); // Only 'publish' paths
    const pageList = paths.dirs
        .filter(dir => dir.substr(-7) === 'publish') // Only 'publish' paths
        .map(dir => {
            const name = dir.split('/').slice(-2)[0];
            const subpages = fileList
                .filter(filePathArray => filePathArray[filePathArray.length - 3] === name) // select those files whose "parent content slug" matches 'name'
                .map(filePathArray => filePathArray[filePathArray.length - 1].replace(mdxSuffix, ''));
            return { name, subpages };
        });
    console.log('pageList at end:');
    console.log(pageList);
});
```

You will see that :

- `fileList` is constructed with  a `paths.files.map().filter()` pattern.
- `pageList` is constructed with a `paths.dirs.filter().map()` pattern.
- for each entry in `pageList`, `subpages` is constructed with a `fileList.filter().map()` pattern.

Barring mistakes on my part, that should give the same result.

*untested*